# mysql - connect two cells from different tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to do something that should be very basic but impossible to bypass that issue.
I have 2 tables. The first one is a table that stocks the page architecture and the second one stocks some contents. Occasionally, I'd like to call some contents from my first table. I've tried to create a Foreign Key but that only displays the id of the content.

Here is the structure of my table 1 (page models)

1   idPrimaire  int(11)         Non Aucun(e)        AUTO_INCREMENT

2   client  varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
3   nom_document    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
4   type_page   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
5   nom_page    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
6   valeur_contenu  int(11)         Non Aucun(e)
7   ordre   int(11)         Non Aucun(e)

Here is the structure of my table 2 (general contents)

1   idPrimaire  int(11)         Non Aucun(e)        AUTO_INCREMENT

2   nom_liste   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
3   nom_contenu varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
4   valeur_contenu  text    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)
5   type_contenu    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Non Aucun(e)

So what I am looking for is to connect table 1 & 2 in order to be able to call some content from table1

Comment: Yeah but is this a mysql question or sql server question?

Comment: sorry mysql question... I edit right away

Comment: Looks like a simple `INNER JOIN` to me... [which you can learn over here.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: How do you know which rows of `page_models` relate to each row of `general_contents`?  (The science is called "entity-relationship modeling." It would be wise to study it.)  Please [edit] your question to explain this, perhaps with a few rows of sample data. Once you know how each row ("entity" in the jargon) relates to others ("relationship" in the jargon), you'll be able to design your foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a foreign key on your second table so you can `JOIN` them together.

For example

**Table 1**

```
1 idPrimaire int(11) Non Aucun(e) AUTO_INCREMENT
2 client varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
3 nom_document varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
4 type_page varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
5 nom_page varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
6 valeur_contenu int(11) Non Aucun(e)
7 ordre int(11) Non Aucun(e)
```

**Table 2**

```
1 idPrimaire int(11) Non Aucun(e) AUTO_INCREMENT
2 client varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
3 nom_document varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
4 type_page varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
5 nom_page varchar(100) utf8_general_ci Non Aucun(e)
6 valeur_contenu int(11) Non Aucun(e)
7 ordre int(11) Non Aucun(e)
8 table_1_id int(11)
```

Then in SQL you would write

```
 SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.idPrimaire = table_2.table_1_id
```

The join doesn't have to be left, it can be whatever join you need. Once these 2 tables are together, you can fetch them in php using an associative array then get the columns you need.

For example

```
$query = SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.idPrimaire = table_2.table_1_id;
$result = ($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row['nom_page'];
}
```

Comment: I'm testing that right now.. Just to avoid any mistake, I create the foreign key relationship between table1(1) and table2(8)? I also see that you have reproduced the same table structure, why is that essential? Anyway thanks a lot, I'm progressing in my issue

Comment: It doesn't have to be table1(1) and table2(8), there just needs to be matching keys in each table, so that SQL knows how to join

Comment: @Odjone Please let me know how you get on, and if the answer was helpful

Comment: your answer was very helpful... I just succeed. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try "natural join" if u want them combined based on related column, otherwise "full outer join" which returns all records when there is a match in either table1 or table2.

"inner join" will give you values matching on both the table.

Go through this they have explained everything here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot, That's a very good basis to understand what I do. =)